# Is there any bijective map $f: \mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R^{3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The title pretty much says it all.
I'm trying to prove that if I have two maps $T:\mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R^{2}$ and $S: \mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R^{3}$, then $S\circ T$ is not invertible. I think I only need to show that there's no map $f:\mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R^{3}$ such that $f$ is bijective.

.
Is there any invertible map $f:\mathbb R^{2} \to R^{3}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bijective function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.  There is no bijective *linear* function, though, and I assume from your choice of tags that this is relevant to the question you're trying to solve.  To see why, consider the dimensions of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(I'm assuming here that you're thinking of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, and looking for an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map.  If you only ask for $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity the situation is different).

Comment: Good answer! An add on: there is no bijective continuous function.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about linear functions and vector spaces, thanks. And, I think the thing you're talking about when you name dimensions is that, even if I do a map such that $(x,y)$ goes into something like $(x,y,f(x,y))$ I would only be able to map one of the infinite points that go into that specific $x$ and $y$ coordinates, right?